# Word template necessary for multiple users?

Tags: osx-snow-leopard, templates, microsoft-word-2008

I have created a document in MS Word using a company-standard template to define many paragraph and character styles. This document now needs to be passed around to multiple (non-company) co-authors for editing.

Do the other authors need to have a copy of the dotx template file, in addition to the docx file, in order to complete their editing? Since I've gone through and tagged all of the paragraphs, headings, etc. with the desired styles as defined in the template, will those style definitions stay put if I simply email the docx file to them?

If not, do they need to have the dotx file in a particular location on their computer? I created the document using MS Word 2008 on a Mac OSX 10.6.8. Other authors' system-software combinations vary.